# java Regex for matching in file

Tags: java, regex, filereader

I want to find warnings defined by a regex-pattern in a log file 
(yes tex-log file) 
and also find pattern in a tex file which signifies 
that it is a main file.

To that end, I read the file linewise and match the pattern. 
This works fine as long as the pattern is one line only.

```
// may throw FileNotFoundException < IOExcption 
FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(file);
// BufferedReader for perfromance 
BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.MULTILINE);//

// readLine may throw IOException 
for (String line = bufferedReader.readLine();
  line != null;
  // readLine may thr. IOException
  line = bufferedReader.readLine()) {
  if (pattern.matcher(line).find()) {
    return true;
  }
}
return false;
```

If it spreads over lines, this approach becomes difficult.

I tried

```
CharBuffer chars = CharBuffer.allocate(1000);
// may throw IOException 
int numRead = bufferedReader.read(chars);
System.out.println("file: "+file);
System.out.println("numRead: "+numRead);
System.out.println("chars: '"+chars+"'");
return pattern.matcher(chars).find();
```

but this did not work: no matching at all!! 
numRead yields 1000 whereas chars seems to be ''!!!!

Example: pattern: 
\A(\RequirePackage\s*([(\s|\w|,)*])?\s*{\w+}\s*([(\d|.)+])?|
\PassOptionsToPackage\s*{\w+}\s*{\w+}|
%.*$|
\input{[^{}]*}|
\s)*
\(documentstyle|documentclass)

is my pattern for the latex main file. 
One such file is attached in part:

```
\RequirePackage[l2tabu, orthodox]{nag}
\documentclass[10pt, a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}

\title{The dvi-format and the program dvitype}
\author{Ernst Reissner (rei3ner@arcor.de)}

\begin{document}

\maketitle
\tableofcontents

\section{Introduction}
This document describes the dvi file format 
traditionally used by \LaTeX{} 
and still in use with \texttt{htlatex} and that like.
```

How to resolve that problem?

Comment: Update your question by showing us a) the regex pattern you are trying to match and b) a sample of the log file which should be matching.

Answer (score 0):

If you need multi-line matching and the log file is not too large, you can read the whole file in one string:

```
String content = new Scanner(file).useDelimiter("\\Z").next();
```

and then run the regex against `content`.